# Neo4j Cypher data types - creating numerical properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do I create a property that is of a numerical type (that will work with aggregate functions)? I see how to do it in neo4j-shell by executing "man set", but I can't find any documentation on how to do it in Cypher. It appears like you can only do it using pure java. Please tell me I'm wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put them in quotes. :)

```
create (n {i:1, f:2.3});
```

Comment: cypher won't convert 2.3 to a float. You need to do toFloat(2.3)

Comment: @vdisawar this is only true if you're doing load csv or something where it's not a literal. for literal floats you don't need to do `toFloat()`.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, the data does have the numerical datatype when done over REST. My test data had  been created with neo4j-shell and I did not specify a type. For anyone else who makes the same mistake, you must do this in neo4j-shell

```
set -type int ordinal 20
```

Comment: You can overwrite string properties with int properties in cypher.

Comment: `create (n {str:"hi"}); match n set n.str = 1;`

Comment: Oh right. I thought you were implying you could "cast" a string to an int, which I read was not possible in another forum. I appreciate your quick responses.

Comment: Not yet, although there is the reverse operation: `STR(123)` gives you a string. I think eventually they'll have types and casting in Cypher.

Answer (score 0):

```
create(person{name:"Ashish",address:"pune",id:3})
```